# Arp-spoof check in PowerShell

Tags: networking, powershell

To learn some PowerShell I made a tool, I've made before in bash. It pings the subnet for arp values and checks if there is no weird behaviour.

```
function IPv4toBin ($i){
    $b = $i -split '\.' | ForEach-Object {[System.Convert]::ToString($_,2).PadLeft(8,'0')}
    return $b -join ""
}

function Get-IPs($subnet) 
{         
    #Split IP and subnet 
    $IP = ($Subnet -split "\/")[0] 
    $SubnetBits = ($Subnet -split "\/")[1] 
    $IPInBinary = IPv4toBin($IP)

    $HostBits = 32-$SubnetBits 
    $NetworkIDInBinary = $IPInBinary.Substring(0, $SubnetBits)         
    $HostIDInBinary = $IPInBinary.Substring($SubnetBits, $HostBits)         
    $HostIDInBinary = $HostIDInBinary -replace "1","0"

    $imax = [convert]::ToInt32(("1" * $HostBits),2) -1 

    $IPs = @()

    For ($i = 1 ; $i -le $imax ; $i++) 
    { 
        $NextHostIDInDecimal = ([convert]::ToInt32($HostIDInBinary,2) + $i) 
        $NextHostIDInBinary = [convert]::ToString($NextHostIDInDecimal,2) 
        $NoOfZerosToAdd = $HostIDInBinary.Length - $NextHostIDInBinary.Length 
        $NextHostIDInBinary = ("0" * $NoOfZerosToAdd) + $NextHostIDInBinary 
        $NextIPInBinary = $NetworkIDInBinary + $NextHostIDInBinary 

        $IP = @() 
        For ($x = 1 ; $x -le 4 ; $x++) 
        { 
            $StartCharNumber = ($x-1)*8 
            $IPOctetInBinary = $NextIPInBinary.Substring($StartCharNumber,8) 
            $IPOctetInDecimal = [convert]::ToInt32($IPOctetInBinary,2) 
            $IP += $IPOctetInDecimal 
        }  
        $IP = $IP -join "." 
        $IPs += $IP 

    } 
    return $IPs
}

function Check-Spoof($iplist)
{
    $gate_ip = ipconfig | Select-String "Default Gateway" | % { $_.ToString().Split(':')[1].Trim() }
    $gate_ip = $gate_ip[0]
    $gate_mac = arp -a $gate_ip | Select-String $gate_ip |  % { $_.ToString() -split "\s+" }
    $gate_mac = $gate_mac[2].ToUpper()

    echo ""
    echo "Gateway with ip: $gate_ip and mac: $gate_mac"
    echo ""

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $iplist.Count; $i++) 
    {
        if ($iplist[$i] -ne $gate_ip)
        {
            $ip = $iplist[$i]
            $arp_call = arp -a $ip | Select-String "$ip"
            if ($arp_call -ne $null)
            {
                  $call = $arp_call -split "\s+"
                  $mac = $call[2].ToUpper()
                  echo "Active IP: $ip with MAC: $mac"

                  if ($mac -eq $gate_mac)
                  {
                     echo ""
                     echo "You are being Spoofed a duplicate ARP value found"
                     return
                  }
            }
        }
    }
    echo ""
    echo "You are Safe, no duplicate ARP values found."
}

$subnet = "192.168.1.1/24"
$IPLIST = Get-IPs($subnet)
Check-Spoof($IPLIST)
```

I am fairly new to PowerShell, so I'm mostly concerned about the proper syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- split and spread to variables:

  ```
  $IP, $SubnetBits = $Subnet -split '/'
  ```
- your user-function invocation with parentheses is incorrect and works only for single parameter (basically it's interpreted as `user-function (param1)`, the correct syntax is `user-function param1 param2 param3` e.g. `IPv4toBin $IP`
- to get a power of 2 use a bitwise left shift:

  ```
  $imax = (1 -shl $HostBits) - 2
  ```
- use `$array = foreach ($i in 1..$imax) { ... }` to generate arrays directly instead of overly verbose `for` loops and `+=` operator, which recreates the entire array each time
- `ipconfig` may list many networks with empty gateways so you need to account for that or use .NET method ([C# source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13635038)):

  ```
  $gate_ip = [Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces() |
    where { $_.OperationalStatus -eq 'Up' -and $_.NetworkInterfaceType -ne 'Loopback' }|
    foreach { $_.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses } |
    select -expand Address -First 1 |
    select -expand IPAddressToString
  ```
- `Select-String $gate_ip` will incorrectly select the header line with no ARP info in case the interface IP address matches the gateway IP e.g. 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.176
- work with actual numbers instead of binary representation and use bitwise operators:

  ```
  function Get-IPs($subnet) {     
    $IP, $SubnetBits = $Subnet -split '/'
    [uint32]$imax = (1 -shl (32 - $SubnetBits)) - 2
    [uint32]$baseIP = 0
    foreach ($s in ($IP -split '\.')) {
      $baseIP = ($baseIP -shl 8) + $s
    }
    $baseIP = $baseIP -band -bnot ($imax + 1)
    foreach ($i in 1..$imax) { 
      $IP = $baseIP + $i
      "$($IP -shr 24).$($IP -shr 16 -band 255).$($IP -shr 8 -band 255).$($IP -band 255)"
    } 
  }
  ```

  I'm using implicit output here: a statement that consists only of a value (or an expression) is equal to `Write-Output $value_or_expression` and the entire collected output is returned from the function without the need for an explicit `return`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of screen-scraping ipconfig, you can use native PowerShell commands to get the default gateway:

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration | % IPv4DefaultGateway | select -First 1 -ExpandProperty NextHop
```

There may be an arp equivalent too. I haven't looked.

---

This is not PowerShell specific, but as a general rule in any programming language, it's best to have a function that operates on a single item rather than on a list of items. That removes a lot of noise in the function and makes it more readable and flexible. Something like this:

```
function Check-Spoof($gate_ip, $gate_mac, $ip)
{
    if ($ip -ne $gate_ip)
    {
        $arp_call = arp -a $ip | Select-String "$ip"

        if ($arp_call -ne $null)
        {
              $call = $arp_call -split "\s+"
              $mac = $call[2].ToUpper()
              echo "Active IP: $ip with MAC: $mac"

              if ($mac -eq $gate_mac)
              {
                 echo ""
                 echo "You are being Spoofed a duplicate ARP value found"
                 return
              }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want a function that operates on a list of items, then you can define that function in terms of the single-item function

Comment: Id like to disagree on this, utilizing a function with Begin{}, Process{}, and End{} blocks would be better and allow for both lists and single items to be processed and will most likely execute faster as you reduce redundant processing.

Comment: @NickW., clarity is in general the most important thing. You can put the `for` loop inside the function or outside of it. Outside of it is clearer. You shouldn't worry about micro-efficiency unless there is a demonstrated need for it.